# How to parse JSON to two columns in a CSV with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, csv

For some reason I can't log into the same account on my home computer as my work computer.
I was able to get Bo10's code to work, but not abernert's and I would really like to understand why.

Here is my updates to abernert's code:

```
    import csv
    import sys
    import json
    import urllib2

    j = urllib2.urlopen('https://citibikenyc.com/stations/json')
    js = json.load(j)

    citi = js['stationBeanList']

    columns = ('stationName', 'totalDocks', 'availableDocks', 
               'latitude', 'longitude', 'availableBikes')
    stations = (operator.itemgetter(columns)(station) for station in citi)

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_file.writerows(stations)

I thought adding this line `csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)` would fix the object has no attirbute error, but I am still getting it.  This is the actual error:

Andrews-MacBook:coding Andrew$ python citibike1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "citibike1.py", line 17, in <module>
    csv_file.writerows(stations)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writerows'
```

---

So now I have the changed the code to this and the output is just repeating the names of the columns 322 times.  I changed it on line 14 because i was getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "citibike1.py", line 17, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerows(stations)
  File "citibike1.py", line 13, in <genexpr>
    stations = (operator.itemgetter(columns)(station) for station in citi)
NameError: global name 'operator' is not defined: 

import csv
import sys
import json
import urllib2
import operator

j = urllib2.urlopen('https://citibikenyc.com/stations/json')
js = json.load(j)

citi = js['stationBeanList']

columns = ('stationName', 'totalDocks', 'availableDocks', 
           'latitude', 'longitude', 'availableBikes')
stations = (operator.itemgetter(0,1,2,3,4,5)(columns) for station in citi)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerows(stations)
```

Comment: As a side note: Naming a variable `csv` is a bad idea, because it hides the `csv` module. That's especially true in this case, when you want to _use_ the `csv` module—you can't do `csv.writer` after you've done `csv = open(…)`. (Also, it's both simpler and more robust to use a `with` statement instead of explicit `open` and `close`.)

Comment: thank you! could you explain to me how i would use a with statement in this scenario?

Comment: Just do `with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:`, then put the code that uses `csv_file` indented under the `with`, then you don't need to call `close`.

Comment: For more info, look at the very end of the section [Methods of File Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in the tutorial and [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). (There really should be better intro material for `with` statements than there is!)

Comment: One last thing: Your title says "two columns", your question detail says "6 separate columns", and your code builds 322 columns. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: 6 separate columns. thank you for all the help before

Comment: You're calling `writerows` on the `csv_file`, which is a file object, which doesn't know how to `writerows`. (That's what the error "'file' object has no attribute 'writerows' means.) You need to call it on the `csv_writer`, which is a `csv.writer` object, which _does_ know how to write rows.

Comment: hi, i have amended the post again. i received a different error, which i tried to fix, but now i am getting a different output

Comment: Why did you change the code to `operator.itemgetter(0,1,2,3,4,5)(columns)`? That's going to give you `columns[0], columns[1], …, columns[5]`—, because that's exactly what you're asking for. (In other words, it's a very complicated way of just saying `columns[0:6]`.) Making random changes to code you don't understand in hopes it will do what you want never works. If you don't know what `itemgetter` does, read the docs and/or ask someone—or use the more verbose but more-novice-friendly code that you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using the `csv` module, you're using the `pickle` module, and this is what `pickle` output looks like.

To fix it:

```
csvfile = open('output.csv', 'w')
csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(stationList)
csvfile.close()
```

---

Note that you're going out of your way to build a transposed table, with 6 lists of 322 lists, not 322 lists of 6 lists. So, you're going to get 6 rows of 322 columns each. If you want the opposite, just don't do that:

```
stationList = []
for f in citi:
    stationList.append((f['stationName'],
                        f['totalDocks'],
                        f['availableDocks'],
                        f['latitude'],
                        f['longitude'],
                        f['availableBikes']))
```

Or, more briefly:

```
stationlist = map(operator.itemgetter('stationName', 'totalDocks', 'availableDocks',
                                      'latitude', 'longitude', 'availableBikes'),
                  citi)
```

---

However, instead of building up a huge list, you may want to consider writing the rows one at a time.

You can do that by putting `csv.writerow` calls into the middle of the for loop.

But you can also do that just by using `itertools.imap` or a generator expression instead of `map` or a list comprehension. That will make `stationlist` into an iterable that creates new values as needed, instead of creating them all at once.

---

Putting that all together, here's how I'd write your program:

```
import csv
import sys
import json
import urllib2

j = urllib2.urlopen('https://citibikenyc.com/stations/json')
js = json.load(j)

citi = js['stationBeanList']

columns = ('stationName', 'totalDocks', 'availableDocks', 
           'latitude', 'longitude', 'availableBikes')
stations = (operator.itemgetter(columns)(station) for station in citi)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv.writer(csv_file).writerows(stations)
```

Comment: Hmmm. I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "citibike.py", line 23, in <module>
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(csv)
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

Comment: @user2092166: Sorry, you should be writing `stationList`, not `csv`. (But you really need to understand the code well enough to figure that out for yourself, not just blindly copy and paste it.)

Comment: Just saying "i am getting errors" is not useful. You have to explain exactly what you did, and exactly what errors you got, or nobody can help you debug the problem.

Comment: well - i got another error...i am trying to look at the below response to see how i can append your solution and i just cant figure it out

Comment: Again, just saying "i got another error" isn't going to help anyone debug your error. We can't magically guess what you might be doing wrong in code we can't see. You need to post the actual code, and a description of what you expect, and what happens (with an actual traceback) somewhere. Whether that means editing this question, filing a new question, putting everything at http://pastebin.com and posting a link here, etc. depends on the situation, but you have to do _something_.

Comment: i have edited the post up top...i figured i was missing the csv.writer fucntion, but i guess i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As abarnert mentions, you're not actually using the `csv` module that you've imported.

Also, your logic for storing the columns might actually be transposed. I think you might want to do this instead (*edited to fix the tuple/list confusion*):

```
import csv
import json
import urllib2

j = urllib2.urlopen('https://citibikenyc.com/stations/json')
js = json.load(j)

citi = js['stationBeanList']

columns = ["stationName", "totalDocks", "availableDocks", "latitude", "longitude", "availableBikes"]
station_list = [[f[s] for s in columns] for f in citi]

with open("output.csv", 'w') as outfile:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  csv_writer.writerows(station_list)
```

Comment: i am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "citibike1.py", line 15, in <module>
    _ = csv_writer.writerows(station_list)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: IIRC, in 2.x, `writerows` requires an iterable of _sequences_, not just an iterable of iterables, so you need to change the internal genexp into a listcomp to make this work.

Comment: Also, why are you assigning the result of writerows (which is always `None`) to a variable?

Comment: Whoops, I meant to put brackets instead of parens. I couldn't remember whether writerows returned something, but I know writerow did, hence the assignment.

Comment: `writerow` also always returns `None`. (What could it return of any use, anyway?) Also, in Python, if something returns a value you don't need, you can and should just ignore it. Assigning it to a variable gets in the way of the GC (and the JIT optimizer, in PyPy/Jython/IronPython), and of every human reader.

Comment: I'm used to Python 3's behavior, where `writerow` returns the number of bytes written. For example `x = csv.writer(outfile).writerow((1, 2))` sets x to `5` in my interpreter.

Comment: @Bo102010: That [isn't documented](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow); it's just an accident of CPython 3.0-3.3 that you shouldn't rely on. And again, even if it _were_ documented to return a value, if you want to ignore it, just ignore it. (Notice that even [other functions in the `csv` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/csv.py#l139) call `writerow` and ignore the return value.)

Comment: Understand and agree; I amended my answer earlier. I made the mistake once of doing writerow in a large loop in the interpreter and getting a huge amount of spam written to the screen. Assigning the return value to a variable avoids that.

Comment: @Bo102010: Ignored return values don't print to the screen. And assigning the return value to a variable doesn't affect that in either way.

Comment: could you explain the differences between this: "stations = (operator.itemgetter(columns)(station) for station in citi)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.writerows(stations)" and this "station_list = [[f[s] for s in columns] for f in citi]

with open("output.csv", 'w') as outfile:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  csv_writer.writerows(station_list)" are?

Comment: user2092166: these are two different ways of making an "iterable of iterables" (first one) or "list of lists" (second one) and then writing them to a CSV file. In this application there's not much difference between the two, but the former avoids making an unnecessary copy of the input and thus saves memory.

abarnert, the interactive interpreter does print the bytes to the screen, which is what I meant. I fully understand and agree with your position on the whole topic.

Comment: @Bo102010: Actually, the first one is an iterable of tuples—in other words, it still generates _each row_ completely in memory, it just doesn't do _all of the rows_ in memory.

Comment: @user2092166: Meanwhile, have you read the documentation to the `csv` module, the links about `with` statements, etc.? Again, you really need to understand this code. If you can't figure out how to walk through it, you won't be able to debug it, expand on it, apply it to similar problems, etc. And asking people to explain things to you that you could read in the docs (which you've already been given links to) is not helpful. If you aren't willing to read nicely-written official docs, why are you willing to read the on-the-spot ramblings of couple of idiots?